# Can I temporarily disable asian fonts for testing purposes?

Tags: html, css, utf-8, fonts, asianfonts

I manage a Japanese website for my company.
Because I live in Japan all of my devices have Asian fonts and language support installed. I know however that for example my mother has several devices that cannot read Japanese fonts and will display boxes and garble (from the US).

We have foreign customers and I'd love for an easy way to check what our English website looks like when a user -does not- have Asian fonts installed so I can see if there are any characters that are not carrying over properly.

Sometimes an apostrophe or a math symbol does not translate properly and leaves a funny space/box.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to spin up a new virtual machine with an OS that does not have the support for Asian languages and use it to check the website.

Comment: I will try that on a home computer. Thanks for the idea.